# Add delay to jQuery Validator custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

**[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/hqq7s66g/)** that will show exactly what is happening. It took a while to assemble, but something I should have done from the start.

I am using [jQuery mobile to create an autocomplete list](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html).

I am using inline validation, so that when a user goes from one input to another the input is validated. This is the functionality I would like to maintain if possible.

```
$form.validate({
'rules': {
    'myInput': {
        'required': true,
        'myCustomMethod': true
         }
    },
    'onkeyup': false,
    'onfocusout': function(element) {
        if ($element.attr('id') === 'myInput')
        {
           setTimeout(function() {
             // Just need a way for the input's value to get updated first
             // call my custom method
            }, 1000);
        }
    },
    'submitHandler': function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
...

$.validator.addMethod('myCustomMethod', function(value, element) {
    // myobject is stored values to validate against.
    $.each(myobject, function(i, thing) {
        if (value === thing)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
 }, Messages.inValidInputValue);
```

The value of `myInput` **must** match a value that is in the autocomplete list. If it does not, the input should be considered invalid.

When the `blur` event for the `myInput` element, `myCustomMethod` is getting fired. The problem is, I am leaving the field to select an option that was created by the autocomplete. I am struggling to find a way to validate `onfocusout`, but only after I have chosen something from the list.

The `blur` event and the `click/touch` event are happening at the exact same time. Which, is expected functionality. However, the `blur` event is firing first, so when I try to click/touch an option from the autocomplete list, I get an error that the `myInput` is invalid. Which is true - but I'm trying to select a value that is valid...

I updated my code above - with a timeout to help show...kind of what I'm trying to do. It's like I need the blur event to start, but then wait for me to click an item in the list, THEN validate.

But, it is possible that a user could not choose an option from the list. In which case the input should be considered invalid (which is why I need the blur event).

I have read I could `return "pending"` but I am always getting the same response as `return true`. Maybe I'm not incorporating it correctly though. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: So you're missing the part of the `onfocusout` function that actually triggers the validation.  Refer to the default `onfocusout` function within the plugin.  This will trigger the validation: `this.element(element)`  Just run that line after your delay.

Comment: Which JQM version are you using? Pls add a sample of html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain about what you're asking but the following might work.

1)  Disable `onfocusout` for the one field or the entire form.  Not sure what you'd need as I cannot see the rest of your code.  The idea here is to stop the normal events from triggering validation on your field.  (Maybe you'll need to disable `onkeyup` validation as well?)

2)  Then when you're ready to validate this particular field, you can can trigger it yourself with the `.valid()` method.  `$('#myField').valid()` will trigger validation on only this one field and return a boolean indication for pass/fail.

Note that all rules are applied the same and that you still need to call the `.validate()` method to initialize the plugin on your form.

---

EDIT:

Based on OP's edit:

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    if ($element.attr('id') === 'myInput') {
       setTimeout(function() {
            this.element(element);  // trigger validation after the delay
        }, 1000);
    } else if ( !this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element)) ) {
        this.element(element);  // otherwise, trigger validation normally
    }
},
```

Comment: In essence, the value of my text input MUST be one of the values listed in the autocomplete list. So when the user clicks a value in the list, the `blur` event is fired - which will return an error since the input value does not match one in the list. Everything is working as it should - it's working a little too well. :)

Comment: @dragonslovetacos, then please explain better and construct a more complete example of the problem in your OP.