# jQuery Validator custom method returns false but can still submit form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/hqq7s66g/)** that will show exactly what is happening. It took a while to assemble, but something I should have done from the start.

If you comment out the rule, and un-comment the timeout logic, you won't get an error - but you can still submit the form.

If you leave the custom method in the rules, it's fired - and you will always see the error. Which makes sense because the blur and the click event(s) are one in the same.

I am using the [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a form. I have a custom method (below) that is called in the `'onfocusout'` property. The location input is an autocomplete. So, I am using `setTimeOut` to create a slight delay to give the user a chance to choose something from the list.

The logic is working properly, and the UI is showing the error correctly if the location is invalid. I am still able to submit the form however. [According to the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/) it looks like I am returning the error correctly? There must be something else I'm missing to prevent the form from getting submitted.

The custom method:

```
$.validator.addMethod('hasValidCityStateZip', function(value, element) {
  return (App.isValidLocation) ? true : false;
}, Messages.invalidCityStateZip);
```

HTML:

```
<form>

    ....

    <input type="text" type="text" id="location" name="site" placeholder="City, State/Province, ZIP/Postal Code" data-clear-btn="true" value="" />

    ....

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: I've never seen somebody call a specific method from within `onfocusout`.  Typically, `onfocusout` simply triggers validation for the field, the method is declared elsewhere, and automatically handled by the plugin.  Also, what exactly was wrong with the answer provided here?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25317124/594235

Comment: @Sparky My bad - I should have updated that post.

Answer (score 0):

When you click `submit` the plugin evaluates the form using the rules you've declared, either within `.validate()` or by another standard method.  Since you apparently have not declared the `hasValidCityStateZip` method anywhere outside of the `onfocusout` function, this custom method is only going to be called upon `blur`; it's not going to be called when the submit button is clicked.

**EDIT**:

After looking at [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/hqq7s66g/), it seems like you're already doing 95% of the validation yourself and the plugin is left only with the simple task of placing the label element. So I think you'd be much better off just writing an entire custom form validation function from scratch.

Comment: That's the trouble. I can't have it in the rules - I'm unable to set a timeOut in the custom method. I'm working on a JS filddle to help. Should have done that long ago.

Comment: @dragonslovetacos, If you cannot set the custom method within the rules (BTW- why?), then it will never be called when you click `submit`.

Comment: When I set it in the rules, the custom method is fired immediately when the user blurs the input. The user is attempting to choose a value from the auto-complete list (which causes the blur event to fire). So the form always shows an error that the location is invalid. The user then has to click again to choose a valid location.

Comment: @dragonslovetacos, how many inputs on your form?  Your situation is so unique, it may be easier for you to simply write your own validation function from scratch rather than trying to to trick the plugin into working properly.

Comment: Not that many - it's just a super unique situation I think. I have updated my post(s) with a JSFiddle. Thank you so much for all of your help!!

Comment: @dragonslovetacos, after looking at your jsFiddle, it seems like you're already doing 95% of the validation yourself and the plugin is left only with the simple task of placing the label element.  So yes, I think you'd be much better off just writing the entire validation function from scratch.